# PC is turned off when plugged in HHD power cable

Tags: hard-drive, power

I have a system with following specs :

---

HP Compaq 8000 Elite

PSU : 240W

HDD : 1TB Western-Digital

RAM : 8GB (4x2GB)

CPU : Core2Quad Q6600

VGA : On-Board

---

When I plug in power connector into the HDD and press system power button, it turns on a while and then immediately will turned off!
But with no HDD power plugged in, the system works fine!!
Also the system works good with CD-drive and another hardware parts.
It only have problem with HDD.

*** EDIT ***

I forgot to write this temporary fix :

1. I remove HDD power connector.
2. For 5-10 minutes the PC is running with no hard.
3. Again reconnect HDD power, and the system works and windows will load!

However next morning with pressing power button, this problem persists.

---

Please guide me how to find the fixes!!??

Thanks.

Comment: How old is your hdd and psu

Comment: about 2 years old.

Answer (score 0):

Replace the PSU in the computer - possibly with something a bit more powerful - if it used to work, most likely a cap is blown in the PSU - its relatively common.   In any case, the PSU is not generating enough power to spin up the system and hard drive.

It is also remotely possible that the hard drive is stuffed and is trying to draw more power then the PSU can provide.   This should not happen though.

Comment: But I forgot to write that when I turn on the system with no HDD connected for 5 minutes and then reconnect HDD power, the PC is turned on and it works fine. I must repeat this process every time I want to start the PC after a long time it was turned off!

Comment: This pretty definitively points to a dying PSU. Your PSU can't handle the startup current required by the system.